# Set Error Div positioning on left side of textfield - Jquery Validation Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery Validation Engine.

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

It shows error messages on the right side of each textfield.

How can I set it to the left side for a specific textfield?

I have 4 fields i.e name, email,phone,password.

I want to show error div on left side for email textfield.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the position directly in the element or you can also customize the position by setting the `data-prompt-position`. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinbtechdf/GaT5w/6/).

you can set the position like the following also. This is mentioned in their documentation:

```
  <input value="http://" class="validate[required,custom[url]] text-input" type="text" name="url" id="url" data-prompt-position="topLeft:70" />

  <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req" id="req" data-prompt-position="bottomLeft:20,5" />

  <input value="too many spaces obviously" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber]]" type="text" name="special" id="special" data-prompt-position="bottomRight:-100,3" />
```

You can also refer the demo of Positioning here http://www.jqueryrain.com/?_VzOqXOT

Comment: Great. It works. This helps a lot. http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoPositioning.html